# Python - convert contours to image

Tags: image, matplotlib, contour

I would like to convert to image a subset of contours from an array. I tried this:

```
z = (plt.contour(data, [0.0, 0.2, 0.4]))
plt.imshow(z)
```

I get this error

```
    ...\matplotlib\image.pyc in set_data(self, A)
    428         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
    429             not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, np.float)):
--> 430             raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
    431 
    432         if (self._A.ndim not in (2, 3) or

TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Is there a way around this, or another way to save contours to image?

*** UPDATED ***

Below is a complete Notebook-style example:

```
# preliminaries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

# create data - from a classic Matplotlib example
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# plot data as image
# image is displayed correctly
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.imshow(Z, cmap='bone_r')

# plot subset of data as contours
# contours are displayed correctly
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
z = (plt.contour(Z, [0.0, 0.2, 0.4]))

# overlay - this gives the error message above
fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig3.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.imshow(Z, cmap='bone_r')
plt.imshow(z)
plt.show()
```

**UPDATED 2**

I used the code below to capture all contours for the desired z level. See accepted answer and comments.

```
for collection in z.collections:
  paths = collection.get_paths()
  for path in paths:
    line=(path.vertices)`  
    plt.plot(line[:,0], line[:,1], 'k-')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contour is a curve, and you are trying to plot a curve **as** an image.

Instead, use `z.collections[index].get_paths()[0].vertices` to get the curve.  You can then plot this curve as a line **on** the image.  I also wonder, though, whether you just want to put normal contours on the curve, so here I'll include both examples...

A normal contour plot:
[image]

One with a modified contour (here, shifted right), directly plotted on the image
[image]

```
# preliminaries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data - from a classic Matplotlib example
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-4, 6, 0.25) # test with asymmetric range since y-axis origin can sometimes lead to problems
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# plot data as image
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

ax = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.imshow(Z, cmap='bone_r')

# If you just want to plot the contous on the image, just don't
#    create a new figure, or z = ax.contour(Z, [0.0, 0.2, 0.4])
#    if the "ax" variable name is unique
# plot subset of data as contours
#fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

#ax = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
z = (plt.contour(Z, [0.0, 0.2, 0.4]))

# overlay - this gives error message
fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

ax = fig3.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.imshow(Z, cmap='bone_r')
# If you want to plot the controus yourself, you can do it like this...
index = 2  # look at the first contour
line = z.collections[index].get_paths()[0].vertices
line = np.copy(line)  # make a copy so manipulations don't change the original contour
line[:,0] += 1.0  # shift it to the right (as an example of something we can do only easily with the data for the contour line
plt.plot(line[:,0], line[:,1], 'r-')

plt.show()
```

Note in all of these, you might also want to use `origin="lower"` depending on what you're going for (that is, note that when I shifted the y-axis, I shift the range up, so the center should move down in the image, but the y-axis is traditionally inverted in images, and `"lower"` fixes this).

Comment: Added the example to the question, as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. One more thing, what do I iterate over if I want to stack in one array all contours for a specific level(for example, the three red ones)?

Comment: `get_paths`.  The `0` in my example picks off the first path.